# Simplify code when button label is similar

Tags: button, optimization, autohotkey

I have a gui with 3 buttons who all have same label. I do similar function with all 3 buttons: open up a file and place path of opened file in an edit box. My code is ugly. can it be simplified without changing the button labels?

Here is the code sample:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent
#Warn


Gui, Add, Button, x212 y10 w120 h30 gFileOpen1, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, x212 y50 w120 h30 gFileOpen2, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, x212 y100 w120 h30 gFileOpen3, Browse
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y10 w180 h30 vMyEdit4, Edit
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y50 w180 h30 vMyEdit5, Edit
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y100 w180 h30 vMyEdit6, Edit
Gui, Show, x177 y188 h147 w344, New GUI Window
Return

FileOpen1:
    Gui +OwnDialogs
    FileSelectFile, SelectedFileName,,, Open File, Exe Files(*.exe)
    if SelectedFileName =  ; No file selected.
        return
    GuiControl,, MyEdit4, %SelectedFileName%
return

FileOpen2:
    Gui +OwnDialogs
    FileSelectFile, SelectedFileName,,, Open File, Exe Files(*.exe)
    if SelectedFileName =  ; No file selected.
        return
    GuiControl,, MyEdit5, %SelectedFileName%
return

FileOpen3:
    Gui +OwnDialogs
    FileSelectFile, SelectedFileName,,, Open File, Exe Files(*.exe)
    if SelectedFileName =  ; No file selected.
        return
    GuiControl,, MyEdit6, %SelectedFileName%
return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```

**EDIT:**

All 3 buttons use `Browse` as a label. I want to have one `g_Action` so instead of having `gFileOpen1` `gFileOpen2` and `gFileOpen3` I can have just **one** `gFileOpen` and perhaps **one** `FileRead`.  Hope that helps clarify the question.

**EDIT2:**
Took irrelevant parts out of the code but original question still stands: In the absence of a name for the control, in this case a `button` and relying on a label, how can you distinguish the action of the button so not to have multiple `g_Action` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter when using an array

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent
#Warn

Array := {"FileOpen1":"MyEdit4","FileOpen2":"MyEdit5","FileOpen3":"MyEdit6"}

Gui, Add, Button, x212 y10  w120 h30 vFileOpen1 gFileOpen, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, x212 y50  w120 h30 vFileOpen2 gFileOpen, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, x212 y100 w120 h30 vFileOpen3 gFileOpen, Browse
Gui, Add, Edit  , x12  y10  w180 h30 vMyEdit4            , Edit
Gui, Add, Edit  , x12  y50  w180 h30 vMyEdit5            , Edit
Gui, Add, Edit  , x12  y100 w180 h30 vMyEdit6            , Edit

Gui, Show, x177 y188 h147 w344, New GUI Window

Return

FileOpen:
{
    Gui +OwnDialogs
    FileSelectFile, SelectedFileName,,, Open File, Exe Files(*.exe)
    if SelectedFileName =  ; No file selected.
        return

    GuiControl,, % array[A_GuiControl], %SelectedFileName%
}
Return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Elegant solution. My main problem was not finding under `button` in the `GUI` documentation ability to add variable name plus `g_Label` and `Caption` as can be seen here:http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Button

Answer (score 0):

**Answer courtesy of Skwire**

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent
#Warn

Gui, Add, Button, x212 y10  w120 h30 vFileOpen1 gFileOpen, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, x212 y50  w120 h30 vFileOpen2 gFileOpen, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, x212 y100 w120 h30 vFileOpen3 gFileOpen, Browse
Gui, Add, Edit  , x12  y10  w180 h30 vMyEdit4            , Edit
Gui, Add, Edit  , x12  y50  w180 h30 vMyEdit5            , Edit
Gui, Add, Edit  , x12  y100 w180 h30 vMyEdit6            , Edit

Gui, Show, x177 y188 h147 w344, New GUI Window

Return

FileOpen:
{
    Gui +OwnDialogs
    FileSelectFile, SelectedFileName,,, Open File, Exe Files(*.exe)
    if SelectedFileName =  ; No file selected.
        return

    If ( A_GuiControl = "FileOpen1" )
    {
        GuiControl,, MyEdit4, %SelectedFileName%
    }
    Else If ( A_GuiControl = "FileOpen2" )
    {
        GuiControl,, MyEdit5, %SelectedFileName%
    }
    Else If ( A_GuiControl = "FileOpen3" )
    {
        GuiControl,, MyEdit6, %SelectedFileName%
    }
}
Return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```